# Is there a one-liner for using default values with Read-Host?

Tags: powershell, refactoring

I've written something like this to specify default values for prompts.

```
$defaultValue = 'default'
$prompt = Read-Host "Press enter to accept the default [$($defaultValue)]"
if ($prompt -eq "") {} else {
    $defaultValue = $prompt
    }
```

Can it be shortened further?

Here is my attempt.

```
$defaultValue = 'default'
$prompt = Read-Host "Press enter to accept the default [$($defaultValue)]"
if (!$prompt -eq "") {$defaultValue = $prompt}
```

I want a one-liner, so I'm gonna hold out accepting an answer until then.

N.b. `$defaultValue` should be stored independently of the one liner. Similar to the example above.

I've accepted the answer which lead me to the solution I was looking for.

```
$defaultValue = 'default'
if (($result = Read-Host "Press enter to accept default value $defaultValue") -eq '') {$defaultValue} else {$result}
```

And for those of you asking why. The reason is because it is easier on the eyes of whoever comes after me. Less is always more, when clarity is not sacrificed. IMHO.

EDIT;

Instead of a single line, perhaps I should have said a single phrase?
I've added this edit clarify whilst a few answers I have seen use are using a semi-colon.

Comment: cramming as much code as possible into a single line is never easier on the eyes. IMHO.

Comment: The second code block in the question is the most immediately understandable to me. Also the "solution you were looking for" code block appears to me not to change any variables.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Shortest Version I could came up with:

```
if (!($value = Read-Host "Value [$default]")) { $value = $default }
```

This version doesn't have to use else.

Comment: I've moved the accepted answer to you, shortest and clearest answer so far. Thank-you.

Comment: For PowerShell 7: `$value = ($v = Read-Host "Value") ? $v : 'default'`

Comment: Assign if value given: `if ($value = Read-Host "Value [$current]") { $current = $value }`

Answer (score 28):

```
$defaultValue = 'default'
$prompt = Read-Host "Press enter to accept the default [$($defaultValue)]"
$prompt = ($defaultValue,$prompt)[[bool]$prompt]
```

If you absolutely have to have it in one line:

```
$defaultValue = 'default'
($defaultValue,(Read-Host "Press enter to accept the default [$($defaultValue)]")) -match '\S' |% {$prompt = $_}
```

Comment: This is good, I want the last 2 lines in a single line before I accept an answer though.

Comment: Why? What possible reason is there for requiring a one liner? Do you come from a perl background?

Comment: What EBGreen said. But FTR: you can always put 2 statements on one line by separating them with a semicolon.

Comment: I wrapped this into a function:
`function Read-Default($text, $defaultValue) {
    $prompt = Read-Host "$($text) [$($defaultValue)]";
    return ($defaultValue,$prompt)[[bool]$prompt];
}`

Comment: What does the last "[bool]" (before the last $prompt) in the first example do?

Comment: @granadaCoder - that casts the value of $prompt to boolean (true/false). If it's null, it will be $false. If not null it will be $true.  This then gets cast as [int] implicitly to use as an array index (0 if $false, 1 if $true).

Answer (score 12):

```
if(($result = Read-Host "Press enter to accept default value [default]") -eq ''){"default"}else{$result}
```

Comment: Can this be done without typing 'default' twice? I.e. can default be stored in a variable?

Comment: This suits me: `$defaultValue = 'default'
if (($result = Read-Host "Press enter to accept default value $defaultValue") -eq '') {$defaultValue} else {$result}`. Thank-you.

Comment: A one-liner that doesn't repeat the variable name: `'Default Value' | %{If($Entry = Read-Host "Enter a value ($_)"){$Entry}Else{$_}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
$DefaultValue="Foobar"

.... (Optional other code) ....

$Value=if($Value=(Read-Host "Enter value [$DefaultValue]")){$Value}else{$DefaultValue}
```

Just threw this together to re-use a previously entered config value while still allowing user to change it if needed... The accepted answer is missing the assignment portion and uses a hardcoded "Default" value...

There is a function (from other languages) called "Ternary Operator" or "Binary Operator"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (the 'xx : yy ? zz' style one) and there are several people who have submitted functions to implement its behavior in Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

For me this is the shortest, easiest to use, and doesn't repeat the variable value or name:

```
$ChosenValue = 'Default Value' | %{ If($Entry = Read-Host "Enter a value ($_)"){$Entry} Else {$_} }
```

The magic sauce is the `|%{}` that pipes the default value to ForEach, allowing repeating the default value (aliased as `$_`) in the message and return value. It also depends on the fact that the assignment operator returns the value assigned for the purposes of the `If` statement. This assigned value will be treated as `$true` when an entry is provided, or `$false`(empty) when the `[Enter]` key is pressed instead.

Thanks go to @ojk's excellent answer which I considered the easiest to use and read, but I agree with @bluekeys that it's better to avoid repeating the default value and  assigned variable name. Having the intermediate `$Entry` variable hasn't proven to be an inconvenience.

I use this method frequently to define function or script parameters with defaults that can be overridden at run time:

```
param(
    $hostname = ('google.com' | %{ If($Entry = Read-Host "Host name ($_)"){$Entry} Else {$_} }) 
)
Write-Host $hostname
```

Running:

```
Host name (google.com): 
google.com

Host name (google.com): facebook.com
facebook.com
```

Also, as @E.Sundin pointed out, Powershell 7 finally has a ternary operator that makes this syntax much simpler. Unfortunately many of us work on legacy systems that won't get version 7 in the near future.

EDIT: here's a slightly shorter version without an intermediate `$Entry` variable:

```
$hostname = 'google.com' | %{(Read-Host "Host name ($_)"),$_} | ?{$_} | Select -First 1
```

It makes an array containing the `Read-Host` response and the default value, then filters to exclude empty values, and selects the first (there would be two if the user responded).

Comment: This is a little code-golfy, but saves a few characters: 
`$hostname = 'google.com' |%{@((Read-Host "Host name ($_)"),$_| ?{$_})[0] }` 
It makes an array of the response and the default - then returns the first non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator kept giving me errors. Based on other answers this is the best I found - assuming `$value` is already set to a default value:

```
$value = if ($_ = Read-Host "Value - $value") {$_} else {$value}
```

You may want to make this a function:

```
Function Input($prompt, $default) {
    $input = Read-Host "$prompt [$default]"
    $input = if ($input -eq [string]::empty) {$default} else {$input}
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "> $input `n"
    return $input
}

$value = & Input "Confirm value" $value
```

The `&` (call operator) before the call to `Input` will allow the function to write the result to the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
$prompt = ( ($defaultValue='a_default_value'), (Read-Host "Please enter something [$defaultValue]")) -match '\S' | select -last 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The given answers doesn't satisfy me (and don't work for me) but gave me enough input to came up with the shortest one-liner.

```
if (($prompt = Read-Host -Prompt "Your Text [your default]") -eq "") {$prompt= "your default"}
```

Why adding an else? If user inputs nothing it does $prompt="your default" (could be a variable of course). If he adds something, its stored in %prompt already and you can leave the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a function for that:

```
Function Read-HostDefault($Prompt, $Default) {
    if ($default) {
        $prompt = "$prompt [$default]"
    }
    $val = Read-Host $prompt
    ($default,$val)[[bool]$val]
}
```

Which gives:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Read-HostDefault "Enter port" 5432
Enter port [5432] : 
5432

PS C:\Windows\system32> Read-HostDefault "Enter port" 5432
Enter port [5432] : 1234
1234

PS C:\Windows\system32> Read-HostDefault "Enter port"
Enter port : 2468
2468
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a switch statement in a single line like this:

```
param([string]$myVariable = $($($val = $(Read-Host "Enter value")); $(Switch -regex ($val) { ".+" { $val } default { "my default value" } })))
```

The `-regex` `.+` will match one or more characters, this would include any white space characters so maybe you want to strip out white space when doing the switch match i.e. `\S.+`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have $defaultValue:

`$newValue = if ($value = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter a value ($defaultValue)") { $value } else { $defaultValue }`

This should work